# Magento 2: Update monolog/monolog

Tags: magento2, monolog

I want to update **monolog/monolog** version to **^1.17**

I tried to do the same using below commands

```
composer require monolog/monolog:^1.17
composer update
```

But it gives below errors.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.1.5 requires monolog/monolog 1.16.0 -> satisfiable by monolog/monolog[1.16.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.1.5 requires monolog/monolog 1.16.0 -> satisfiable by monolog/monolog[1.16.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.1.5 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.1.5].
```

Comment: I've already mentioned it in question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to upgrade from 2.1.6 to 2.1.7 and getting a composer error](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182430/trying-to-upgrade-from-2-1-6-to-2-1-7-and-getting-a-composer-error)